# Get numbers between start and stop and restart counter if maximum is exceeded

Tags: python

My goal is to get all numbers between `start` and `stop`, inclusive. If the starting point exceeds a defined maximum (`restart_point`), it should start from 1 again

For example:

```
start = 4
stop = 8
restart_point = 12
```

result should be: `[4, 5, 6, 7, 8]`

```
start = 9
stop = 3
restart_point = 12
```

result should be: `[9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3]`

The following code works, but I find it a bit complicated. I would be happy about alternative solutions.

```
start = 10
stop = 3
restart_point = 12

if stop - start < 0:
  difference = restart_point - start + stop
else:
  difference = stop - start

numbers = []

r = 0
for i in range(difference + 1):
  val = i + start
  if val > restart_point:
    r += 1
    val = r
  numbers.append(val)

print(numbers)
# result -> [10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: stop can be lower that start?

Comment: yes because I want a range of numbers. If stop is 2 and start is 3 I want to get the numbers [3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,1,2]

Comment: In your example restart_point is 12, right?

Comment: Yes exactly restart_point is 12 for all examples

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your simple examples, it appears that I can assume that both stop and start are between 1 and restart_point, inclusive.  This makes it simple enough:

```
start, stop, restart_point = 10, 3, 12

if stop < start:
    stop += restart_point

numbers = []
for i in range(start-1, stop):
    val = i % restart_point + 1

    numbers.append(val)

print(numbers)
```

Output:

```
[10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this outputs zero at the reset point, unlike the OP's expected output.

Comment: Much easier than my solution. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Remember to use mod if you need loop in number:

```
start = 9
stop = 3
restart_point = 12

while start % restart_point != stop:
    print(start % restart_point)
    start = start + 1
```

It's 0-index based but it is easy to modified into 1-index based. Leave it to you :)

Answer (score 0):

```
[i for i in range(start, stop+1)] if start<stop else [i for i in range(start, restart_point+1)] + [i for i in range(1, stop+1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I would do something like this:

```
numbers = []
x = start

while x <= stop:
    if x > restart_point:
        x = 1
    numbers.append(x)
    x = x + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
start = 9
stop = 3
restart_point = 12
l = []
if restart_point > stop:
    l = l + [i for i in range(start,restart_point)] + [i for i in range(1, stop+1)]
else:
    l = l + [i for i in range(start, stop+1)]

print(l)
```

**Output:**

```
(python37) C:\Users\Documents>py test.py
[9, 10, 11, 1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here it is:

```
start, stop, restart_point = (10, 3, 12)
x = list(range(start, 1 + min(stop, restart_point))) + \
    list(range(start, 1 + (start>stop) * max(stop, restart_point))) + \
    list(range(1, 1 + (start>stop) *stop))
print(x)
```

**Output**

```
[10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3]
```