# How can I select elements of a list starting by a later element in the list to one that is before in python

Tags: python, list

my question is, how to select multiple elements of a list but starting on a later element of a list to one element that is before, for example:

```
list_1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]

list_2 = list_1[6:3]

print(list_2)

# Result

[7, 8, 1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: I would consider summing up 2 lists: `llst_1[-2:] + list_1[:3]`

Comment: You can't do this with slicing

Comment: hello Juanpa, I know I can't, thats why I'm asking for a solution

Comment: Then you should have a look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53619029/get-numbers-between-start-and-stop-and-restart-counter-if-maximum-is-exceeded

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get numbers between start and stop and restart counter if maximum is exceeded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53619029/get-numbers-between-start-and-stop-and-restart-counter-if-maximum-is-exceeded)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
list_1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
list_2 = list_1[6:]+list_1[:3]
print(list_2)
```

Returns:

```
[7, 8, 1, 2, 3]
```